# \ell with argument in legend

Tags: output-formatting

I want to have
[image]

as a Legend in a figure.

But don't get further than

[image]

Comment: test1 = Plot[X^2, {X, 0, 10}, 
  PlotStyle -> {{RGBColor[0.5, 0.5, 0.5], Dashing[{0.1, 0.01}]}}, 
  PlotLegends -> {Style[
     Subscript[ToExpression["\\ell", TeXForm], L] "\[Lambda]", 
     FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "Times"]}]

Comment: You are trying to attach display items together by just writing one after the other. That is multiplication. Multiplication is commutative (see `Orderless`) so Mathematica will re-arrange the terms. This is wrong for your use case: `a b c`. You want this instead of `Row[{a, b, c}]`. That said, I suggest writing plot labels directly inside of strings, as I demonstrate in the answer below.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 3):

$\ell$ is written as `\[ScriptL]` in Mathematica. It can also by typed as ESC scl ESC.

To type $\ell_L^{(i)}(\lambda)$, and use it as a label, do the following:

1. Type `"\[ScriptL]"`
2. Select the $\ell$, then press Ctrl-Shift-T (Command-Shift-T on macOS) to convert it to Traditional Form. This ensures correct spacing in the formulas you are about to enter.
3. Press `<-` to enter the Traditional Form inline cell you just created. There will be no visual indication that the cursor is within the inline cell.
4. Press Ctrl-`-` to create a subscript, then enter `L`
5. Press Ctrl-`5` to jump to superscript, enter `(i)`
6. Press `->` to exit superscript, type `(` ESC `l` ESC `)`

This is what it looks like on my machine:

[image]

Most of this is documented here: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TwoDimensionalExpressionInput.html You can also search for "two dimensional input".

Step 2. is critical to get good-looking output, but this is not documented very clearly anywhere I know of. Command-Shift-T is, but this specific usage of it to achieve good spacing in strings is not.

If you want a look that fits well with a LaTeX document, consider using my MaTeX package instead.